# É possível simular um servidor FTP em C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, testes, testes-automatizados

Preciso elaborar testes de integração automatizados numa aplicação cujas funcionalidades possuem dependências externas como o FTP. Gostaria de saber se é possível simular um FTP assim como é possível simular um banco de dados com o Moq, por exemplo.

Até então, em minhas pesquisas só encontrei frameworks e pacotes do NuGet que **criam** servidores FTP, mas não é meu objetivo no momento. Queria recorrer a isso apenas se não for possível fazer uma simulação para os testes.

Por enquanto, criei uma classe que se comunica com um servidor FTP existente.

```
    public class FTPComunicacao
    {

        private void DownloadArquivo(string ftpDiretorioPath, string username, string senha, string destinoLocalArquivoPath)
        {
            int bytesRead = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
```

`FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(ftpDiretorioPath));
        ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

        Stream reader = ftp.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(destinoLocalArquivoPath, FileMode.Create);

        while (true)
        {
            bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            if(bytesRead == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        fileStream.Close();
    }

    private FtpWebRequest CriaRequisicaoFtp(string ftpDiretorioPath, string username, string senha, bool keepAlive = false)
    {
        FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(ftpDiretorioPath));

        //Setar o proxy como nulo porque se não, o proxy usado vai receber uma resposta html do monitoramento firewall
        ftp.Proxy = null;
        ftp.UsePassive = true;
        ftp.UseBinary = true;
        ftp.KeepAlive = keepAlive;

        ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, senha);

        return ftp;
    } 

}`